# Calculating taxes before any promotion gets applied - SAP Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, tax, promotions, cybersource

We are using hybris 1811 version. B2C application.

**Tax calculation is done on the net amount i.e. after the promotion is applied.
But we want the tax calculation to be done on the grosss amount i.e first tax should be calculated then promotion should be applied.**

Is there any way we can achieve this? I just started working on this and researching more.

Any leads would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make a hook  that implements CommerceCartCalculationMethodHook and create your logic in beforeCalculate